# Animate svg in list-style-image

Tags: firefox, svg, firefox-addon

The problem refers to Firefox 4+, extension development

I use svg as

```
list-style-image: url(svg)
```

and in some cases i would use animation on svg elements, by i have not DOM object for interacting by javascript.

First reason for using javascript is starting animation on some event.
I don't want dynamically generate <animate> and <svg>, it would be nice if i could get DOM tree and after that attach it on target by **list-style-image**.

How could i do this?

Answer (score 1):

When SVG is being used as an image, not a document, you can't access its DOM from JS.